# How can I use Knex.js to query for the results that satisfy at least one of the conditions?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, knex.js

I have an array containing a set of conditions, each condition has some statements to satisfy:

```
const conditions = [
  {
    statement.one = '',
    statement.two = ''
  },
  {
    statement.one = '',
    statement.two = ''
  },
  ...
]
```

I would like to have Knex know that if the row satisfies one of these conditions, the row gets selected.

It could be easy if I knew how many conditions I have beforehand, I could then just hardcode with `knex().where().orWhere()`. However, I do not know this. Is there a dynamic way with which I can loop through each condition, check fulfillment, and as long as one of those conditions is satisfied, the row gets selected without worrying about the others?

Answer (score 2):

Query builder is mutable. So when you do:

```
const statements = [
   { colName: 'firstName', value: 'Mikael' },
   { colName: 'firstName', value: 'Mr. Mikael' }
];

const builder = knex('myTable');
for (let statement of statements) {
   builder.orWhere(statement.colName, statement.value);
}
let result = await builder;
```

You will get all the rows, whose `firstName` column has value `Mikael` or `Mr. Mikael`